# Rolling average within day using last n values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-polars, rolling-computation

I have a csv file with data in the following format:

```
Time                Open    High    Low     Close
02/01/2018 07:05    8.05    8.05    8.05    8.05
02/01/2018 07:07    8.04    8.04    8.01    8.01
02/01/2018 07:08    8.02    8.02    8.01    8.02
02/01/2018 07:09    8.02    8.02    8.02    8.02
02/01/2018 07:10    8.02    8.02    8.02    8.02
02/01/2018 07:12    8.01    8.01    8.01    8.01
02/01/2018 07:13    8.01    8.01    8.01    8.01
02/01/2018 07:14    8.00    8.00    8.00    8.00
02/01/2018 07:18    7.99    7.99    7.99    7.99
02/01/2018 07:26    7.99    7.99    7.99    7.99
02/01/2018 07:38    7.99    7.99    7.98    7.98
02/01/2018 07:39    7.99    7.99    7.99    7.99
02/01/2018 07:45    7.99    7.99    7.99    7.99
02/01/2018 07:48    7.98    7.98    7.98    7.98
02/01/2018 07:49    7.96    7.96    7.94    7.94
02/01/2018 07:50    7.96    7.96    7.96    7.96
02/01/2018 07:52    7.95    7.95    7.94    7.94
02/01/2018 07:53    7.94    7.94    7.94    7.94
02/01/2018 07:56    7.94    7.94    7.94    7.94
02/01/2018 07:57    7.93    7.93    7.93    7.93
02/01/2018 07:58    7.93    7.93    7.93    7.93
02/01/2018 07:59    7.92    7.92    7.90    7.90
02/01/2018 08:01    7.90    7.90    7.88    7.88
02/01/2018 08:06    7.89    7.89    7.88    7.89
02/01/2018 08:07    7.89    7.90    7.89    7.90
02/01/2018 08:08    7.90    7.90    7.90    7.90
02/01/2018 08:09    7.92    7.92    7.92    7.92
02/01/2018 08:10    7.90    7.90    7.90    7.90
```

where the Time column contains a string (values are for the whole month).

I can extract the Date (e.g. 02/01/2018) from the csv to create the following dataframe:

```
ohlc = jan_data.select(
    pl.col("Time"),
    (pl.col("Time").str.to_datetime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")).alias("DateTime"),
    (pl.col("Time").str.to_date("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")).alias("Date"),
    (pl.col("Time").str.to_time("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")).alias("HM"),
    (2*(pl.col("High")-pl.col("Low"))/(pl.col("Open")+pl.col("Close"))).alias("vol"),
    pl.col("Open"),
    pl.col("High"),
    pl.col("Low"),
    pl.col("Close"),
).set_sorted("Date")
```

I now want to apply the following operation: for the values of **Close** in each day calculate the moving average for a window of the last 20 records. The operation in an Excel file would look like,

[image]

The whole point of this would be to make sure that in calculating the moving average I do not include values from a previous day.

If this is done right the output will be a dataframe that includes all existing fields and will also contain the values of the moving average (with some `na` values since at the start of each day the first 19 values do not produce a 20-records MA).

Any ideas about how to code this using `polars`? In `pandas` it is,

```
ohlc['MA']=ohlc.groupby(['Date'])['Close'].rolling(window).mean().reset_index(level='Date')['Close']
```

where `window=20`.

Comment: Can you also provide the data from Image #1 as text/code? (a runnable example)

Comment: Seconding what @jqurious said, no one wants to hand transcribe any of that.

Comment: OK I changed the image to code.

Comment: still not code... try `df.to_init_repr()` or `df.head(20).to_init_repr()`

Comment: It does not let me save another edit ... Can you read it from a csv ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dedicated [`.rolling_mean()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_mean.html#polars.Expr.rolling_mean) method.

You can combine it with [`.over(...)`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.over.html) for the "group by" functionality.

```py
(pl.read_csv("rolling-average-sample.csv")
   .with_columns(
      DateTime = pl.col("Time").str.to_datetime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
   )
   .with_columns(
      Date = pl.col("DateTime").dt.date().set_sorted(),
      HM   = pl.col("DateTime").dt.time(),
      vol  = (2 * (pl.col("High") - pl.col("Low"))) / (pl.col("Open") + pl.col("Close")),
   )
   .with_columns(
      MA = pl.col("Close").rolling_mean(20).over("Date")
   )
)
```

```
shape: (28, 10)
┌──────────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬─────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ Time             ┆ Open ┆ High ┆ Low  ┆ Close ┆ DateTime            ┆ Date       ┆ HM       ┆ vol      ┆ MA     │
│ ---              ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ str              ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ date       ┆ time     ┆ f64      ┆ f64    │
╞══════════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╪════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ 02/01/2018 07:05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ 8.05  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:05:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:05:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:07 ┆ 8.04 ┆ 8.04 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:07:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:07:00 ┆ 0.003738 ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:08 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.02  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:08:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:08:00 ┆ 0.001247 ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:09 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:09:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:09:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:10 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:10:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:10:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:12 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:12:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:12:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:13 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:13:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:13:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:14 ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0   ┆ 2018-01-02 07:14:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:14:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:18 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:18:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:18:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:26 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:26:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:26:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:38 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.98 ┆ 7.98  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:38:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:38:00 ┆ 0.001252 ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:39 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:39:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:39:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:45 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:45:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:45:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:48 ┆ 7.98 ┆ 7.98 ┆ 7.98 ┆ 7.98  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:48:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:48:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:49 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:49:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:49:00 ┆ 0.002516 ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:50 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.96  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:50:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:50:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:52 ┆ 7.95 ┆ 7.95 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:52:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:52:00 ┆ 0.001259 ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:53 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:53:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:53:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:56 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:56:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:56:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ null   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:57 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:57:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:57:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ 7.9855 │
│ 02/01/2018 07:58 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93  ┆ 2018-01-02 07:58:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:58:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ 7.9795 │
│ 02/01/2018 07:59 ┆ 7.92 ┆ 7.92 ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9   ┆ 2018-01-02 07:59:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:59:00 ┆ 0.002528 ┆ 7.974  │
│ 02/01/2018 08:01 ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.88 ┆ 7.88  ┆ 2018-01-02 08:01:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 08:01:00 ┆ 0.002535 ┆ 7.967  │
│ 02/01/2018 08:06 ┆ 7.89 ┆ 7.89 ┆ 7.88 ┆ 7.89  ┆ 2018-01-02 08:06:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 08:06:00 ┆ 0.001267 ┆ 7.9605 │
│ 02/01/2018 08:07 ┆ 7.89 ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.89 ┆ 7.9   ┆ 2018-01-02 08:07:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 08:07:00 ┆ 0.001267 ┆ 7.9545 │
│ 02/01/2018 08:08 ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9   ┆ 2018-01-02 08:08:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 08:08:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ 7.949  │
│ 02/01/2018 08:09 ┆ 7.92 ┆ 7.92 ┆ 7.92 ┆ 7.92  ┆ 2018-01-02 08:09:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 08:09:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ 7.9445 │
│ 02/01/2018 08:10 ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9   ┆ 2018-01-02 08:10:00 ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 08:10:00 ┆ 0.0      ┆ 7.9395 │
└──────────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: You made it look too easy!

Comment: The `by="Date"` doesn't do anything with an integer window, [it requires a temporal](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_mean.html) e.g. "5h" or "3s" to have an effect. To get the `reset_index(level='Date')` behavior it needs an `over` included. e.g. `pl.col("Close").rolling_mean(20).over("Date")`

Comment: @keraion Hm, that's somewhat confusing. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

In polars there is the `rolling_mean` expression that does exactly that. Given a window size, it will calculate the rolling mean (or moving average). You can eventually also apply weights to the calculation. You can run something like that:

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("Close").rolling_mean(window_size=20).alias("Moving Average"))
```

Output:

```
    shape: (28, 6)
┌──────────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬────────────────┐
│ Time             ┆ Open ┆ High ┆ Low  ┆ Close ┆ Moving Average │
│ ---              ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---            │
│ str              ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64            │
╞══════════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪════════════════╡
│ 02/01/2018 07:05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ 8.05  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:07 ┆ 8.04 ┆ 8.04 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:08 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.02  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:09 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:10 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:12 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:13 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01 ┆ 8.01  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:14 ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0   ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:18 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:26 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:38 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.98 ┆ 7.98  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:39 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:45 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99 ┆ 7.99  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:48 ┆ 7.98 ┆ 7.98 ┆ 7.98 ┆ 7.98  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:49 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:50 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.96  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:52 ┆ 7.95 ┆ 7.95 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:53 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:56 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94  ┆ null           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:57 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93  ┆ 7.9855         │
│ 02/01/2018 07:58 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93  ┆ 7.9795         │
│ 02/01/2018 07:59 ┆ 7.92 ┆ 7.92 ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9   ┆ 7.974          │
│ 02/01/2018 08:01 ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.88 ┆ 7.88  ┆ 7.967          │
│ 02/01/2018 08:06 ┆ 7.89 ┆ 7.89 ┆ 7.88 ┆ 7.89  ┆ 7.9605         │
│ 02/01/2018 08:07 ┆ 7.89 ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.89 ┆ 7.9   ┆ 7.9545         │
│ 02/01/2018 08:08 ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9   ┆ 7.949          │
│ 02/01/2018 08:09 ┆ 7.92 ┆ 7.92 ┆ 7.92 ┆ 7.92  ┆ 7.9445         │
│ 02/01/2018 08:10 ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9  ┆ 7.9   ┆ 7.9395         │
```

└──────────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴────────────────┘